# ResumeDialogAsync on Microsoft Botframework doesn't fire

Tags: botframework

I tried to adapt the following sample: 
[ChoiceFlow Dialog Sample](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/samples/ChoiceFlow%20Dialog%20Sample)

I have a class derived from ComponentDialog with waterfallSteps.
Once I have enough information, I'm starting a new dialog (TroubleshootingDialog).

When the TroubleshootingDialog ends (it ends by calling EndDialogAsync) , I want to analyse data collected in the subdialog and take appropriate actions.

For this, I tried to override ResumeDialogAsync, but it doesn't fire when the subdialog ends.

```
public class ProductFlowDialog : ComponentDialog

In constructor:
var guidedWaterfall = new WaterfallStep[]
{
   LoadChoiceFlowItems,
   PromptChoice,
   ActOnPromptResult,
};

public async Task<DialogTurnResult> PromptChoice(WaterfallStepContext sc, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if ( something)
    {
    }
    else
    {
       // Here we have enough information to start new dialog.
       var result =  await sc.ReplaceDialogAsync("TroubleshootingDialog", wOptions);
       return result;
    }
    public override Task<DialogTurnResult> ResumeDialogAsync(DialogContext outerDc, DialogReason reason, object result = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        // Do something
    }

}
```

Comment: I know this is a bit old. Do you still need assistance with this one?

Comment: project abandoned. too painful. no useful assistance for this techno.